# Do the Wii U remotes work with the old Wii system?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

I know that the old remotes work with the new system, but do the new remotes work with the old system?

Comment: The gamepad most likely will not.  The regular wiimotes, though...should be the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

The Wii U gamepad (the one with the touch screen) and Wii U pro controller will not work on a Wii, and in fact do not work on the Wii mode the Wii U itself has.

All Wiimotes, including those with Wii Motion Plus (the only "new" remotes I'm aware of) will work with both Wii U and Wii systems.

There are no new "remotes" for Wii U. The Wiimotes sold for Wii U use are just Wiimotes, there is no updated Wii U version of the Wiimote. (Note there IS Wii Motion Plus, an updated version of Wiimote, but it is completely compatible for (and was design for) the Wii.)

Comment: Wii Remote Pluses are now packaged in teal-accented Wii U-branded packaging, so this is probably the source of the confusion.